# Looking for a word or phrase that conveys the modification of something in a certain way

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

We have a piece of software that takes client provided data and processes it. A lot of times our client's data will fail because the data in a particular field is either too long or missing altogether. We're creating a system that will truncate the field value if it's too long or infer the value if it's missing. The data may still fail validation at some later point but we don't want the data to fail because it's too long or missing. This will be done before anything else is done to that data.

I'm trying to think of a name for the new system that will represent what we're doing. I don't want to name it something like "ModifyField" because we modify the data for other reasons as well.

To be more specific, I'm looking for something that can serve as a method or class name in the code.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I'm just having a lot of trouble coming up with something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have statistical engines that have sort of similar fields.

It seems that the database world has taken to the word **normalize** (normalization) for examples such as yours.  Used in the context it seems to make sense but it isn't exactly right (well not at all if you understand database normalization).

Another term that we use which I guess is more antiquated, yet still used and far more accurate is **standardize** (standardization).

**Formatted** works too in some cases.  This would imply that you have very specific rules that are triggered.

Note: Actually updating a stats table in our reporting database and forgot we have a **sanitize** filter running.  There is a bonus word.

Answer (score 2):

Why not consider the synomyms of *modify*, such as *adjust* or *adapt*, as in

*AdjustedField*

or

*AdaptedField*

Comment: Adjusted value is my choice too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed a little humour at work, you could try **Transmogrifier** or **Transmogrified**.

While **Transmogrify** is a real word I remember it best from the [Calvin & Hobbes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvin_and_Hobbes) cartoons of the 1980's